# How to transfer data between 2 Android's via USB?

Tags: android, usb

My goal is to transfer simple data (byte array) between two android devices.
After repeatedly reading the [Usb Host](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host) / [Usb Accessory](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory) docs, from my understanding
The host mode is the master, while the accessory mode is the slave.

I have connected two Androids by usb cable, and debug them wirelessly.

## The problem:

Only the device which is in host mode can see the other device

The following steps has been made to identify what went wrong:

Debugging the host device:
using [**UsbManager.getDeviceList()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager#getDeviceList()) does show me the slave devices.

Debugging the slave device:
[**UsbManager.getAccessorylist()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager#getAccessoryList()) returns null
Just incase I have also checked in the slave device if **UsbManager.getDeviceList()** output which is an empty list.

Extra info:

- all androids are above Android 9
- I am using the android.hardware.usb package (com.android.future.usb is not required as docs states)
- Tried to do so with Samsung S22 - Samsung A8
- Tried to do so with Samsung S22 - OnePlus 8T